# Android : startActivityForResult() with BACK button functionality

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activity-finish

I would like to start a new `activity` for a `result`, with `startActvityForResult()`, but I would like to have the `back` button working as normal in the new activity.

Currently when I invoke a new `Activity` for result, nothing happens when I press the back button in the new Activity.

I tried something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(0);
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

in the new Activity, but it didn't work. Still nothing happens when the back button is pressed.

Is there a way around this?

EDIT : I could of course load the last `Activity` in the `onBackPressed()` (can I?), but it seems like a rather crappy hack.

Alex Ady's answer solves my problem, but I still don't understand why `onBackPressed()` doesn't work. The working code now is something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        setResult(1);
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I could use an explanation.

Comment: Have you tried overridding the onKeyevent()

Comment: I'm trying to manipulate the hardware back button's behavior, and I'm pretty sure that the `onBackPressed()` method is called when the back button is pressed.

Comment: Sorry bro, but that did work :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
         finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Although can you tell me why the `onBackPressed` didn't work? Strange isn't it?

Comment: It depends on what phone are you developing. If you are developing on the emulator, `onBackPressed` should work.

Comment: Then it is strange, it should work. In fact you shouldn't override it at all.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too (not overriding) that didn't work either. Actually I had overriden it in the first place because it wasn't working.

Comment: but can anybody tell me , why onbackpressed() not work in this case ??

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't have to override the Back button behavior at all. By default, if the user presses the back button, the result will be `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.

Comment: Isn't working if I don't handle the event. It just stays in the current Activity.

Comment: Brigham is right, pressing back by default finishes the current activity.  So all this nonsense with overriding event functions shouldn't be needed.  Are you doing something in your activity to prevent normal operation of the back button in the first place?

Comment: Do you have another subclass of Activity between this class and the android Activity class that is overriding onBackPressed? That might be what's causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the line that contains the finish().

Comment: Tried it. Nothing changed. :(

Comment: Then what you could try is setting the Result to 0 ouside of this method as your default. And then if one of your conditions is met, you could change it to 1. This way, you don't have to override the onBackPressed() method.