# onBackPressed() not getting called

Tags: java, android, back-button, onbackpressed

I have an android app that has a Main Activity, which when started for the first time will run a Register Activity for the user to log in (or if the user is not logged in already). When in the Register Activity the back button does not do anything. Here is my code:

Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity 
    android:name="com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app.RegisterActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

MainActivity.java (calling the Register Activity):

```
protected void launchRegistrationIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, GET_USERNAME);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "OnActivityResult");
    if (data != null) {
        final String username = data.getStringExtra("USERNAME");
        ...
    }
}
```

RegisterActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Back button pressed");
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Back button pressed (old)");
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
    }
    return true;
}
```

The app is running on Android 4.0 or greater so I don't think I need the `onKeyDown()` override, but I put it in just to try it. As you can see I'm trying to make the back button bring the user back to the Home Screen (as going back to the Main Activity would only bring the user back to the Register Activity since they're still not logged in.

But when I press the back button inside of the Register Activity nothing happens, no log, nothing. I don't know if this has something to do with the activity being called with `startActivityForResult()`. But even `onActivityResult()` isn't being called back when the back button is pressed.

Comment: Wht a `startActivity()` (instead of a `finish()` in `onBackPressed()`? Where is the `setResult()`?

Comment: I'm using `startActivity()` because I want the back button to return the user to the Home Screen instead of back to the Main Activity (which if it did use the `finish()` function it would return the user to the Register Activity because the user would still not be logged in). The `setResult()` is called when the user actually logs in. I didn't include that code as it is not pertinent to when the user presses the Back button.

Comment: Any fragments in the activity?

Comment: does this button work at all on another apps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927628/android-startactivityforresult-with-back-button-functionality

this should help.

Comment: I've found the error and a workaround, but the reasoning does not make a lot of sense to me. I've posted it in an Answer to the original post so it has a little more visibility if someone comes in later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it may solve your problem:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Back button pressed");
    Intent startMain = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(startMain);
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it's still not working. Like I mentioned it's not even hitting the Log.d() function so it's acting as though I'm never hitting the back button.

Comment: why are you using `startActivityForResult` instead of startActivity?

Comment: I'm passing back if the user logged in correctly, the GCM id that they are logged in with, and their username so I can use it in the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to be quick and precises I left out a bit of the code for the RegisterActivity.java as most of the other code is not prevelant to the error. But I did miss one part which to me doesn't seem like it should be affecting the Back button, but it did.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting RegisterActivity");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    Log.d(TAG, "regId = " + regId);

    usernameField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
    registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

    usernameField.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                verifyUsername();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    verifyingDlg = new ProgressDialog(this);
    verifyingDlg.setMessage("Verifying Username...");
}
```

The `usernameField.setOnKeyListener()` was overriding the Back button. I added the following if statement to the listener and now my back button is working as intended (bringing the user back to their home screen).

```
    usernameField.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                verifyUsername();
            }
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Back button pressed (old)");
                Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(startMain);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

My guess is since the `usernameField` is in focus that it's always calling the custom onKeyListener every time the Back button is pressed instead of acting as though the Action is in focus when pressing the Back button. Meaning the overrided `onBackPressed()` and `onKeyDown()` were never called. I've since kept in the added `onBackPressed()` function as a backup if somehow the `usernameField` loses focus.

Comment: Indeed that is not logical (but if it works ^^). The (true) problem must be somewhere else...